# Can an employer apply for exemption from the WARN act and NJ S3170?

Tags: united-states, new-jersey

My employer is expected to release details regarding mass layoffs this week. From what I have found through research, the federal WARN act and NJ S3170 (as the employer is in NJ) come into effect here. The WARN Act stipulates, roughly, that employees must be given a 60 day warning prior to mass layoffs. NJ recently implemented NJ S3170 which extends this calendar warning to 90 days, and also requires minimum 1 week of pay per year of service as a severance. My question is, are there any exemptions allowed? Is there any way an employer can skirt around these laws and mass layoff workers without the calendar warnings? I ask because I brought up these laws to a colleague who brushed them off, claiming the employer could 'easily apply for an exemption'. Is this possible?